# Split a Vec<u8> matching a Vec<u8> pattern

Tags: vector, rust, split

```rust
let input = vec![
    1, 1, 1,
    98, 99,
    2, 2, 2, 2,
    98, 99,
    3, 3
];
```

How can I split by `[98, 99]` to get:

```rust
let output = vec![
    vec![1, 1, 1],
    vec![2, 2, 2, 2],
    vec![3, 3],
];
```

For now I only found a way to split in 2 once, but I need to split as much as the pattern `[98, 99]` is found:

```rust
let sep = vec![98, 99];
let (a, b) = input.split_at(
    res.windows(sep.len())
        .position(|w| w == &sep)
        .unwrap_or_default(),
);
```

Is there a way to do it via stdlib without manually looping through the collection?

Comment: Depends if you consider [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=release&edition=2018&gist=379601459da4d899c5b8dbf52fc4d3cd) "manually looping through the collection"…

Comment: Well, yes it's what I mean. Your solution is very good (and by default I will take it), but I was wondering if a standard fn exists. Like `split` for strings and substrings.

Answer (score 0):

As @BurntShushi5 suggests, use the [`bstr`](https://docs.rs/bstr/0.2.15/bstr/trait.ByteSlice.html#method.split_str) crate:

```rust
use bstr::ByteSlice;

fn main() {
    let input: Vec<u8> = vec![1, 1, 1, 98, 99, 2, 2, 2, 2, 98, 99, 3, 3];
    let pattern: [u8; 2] = [98, 99];
    let result: Vec<Vec<u8>> = input.split_str(&pattern).map(|x|x.to_vec()).collect();
    println!("{:?}", result);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9b0a53272ca8c0fba18e6bd6d6444515)

If you are using (`utf-8`) `bytes` this may do.
The idea is to use the `split` method from `str`:

```rust
fn main() {
    let input: Vec<u8> = vec![1, 1, 1, 98, 99, 2, 2, 2, 2, 98, 99, 3, 3];

    let s = std::str::from_utf8(&input).unwrap();
    let pattern = std::str::from_utf8(&[98, 99]).unwrap();
    let new_vector: Vec<Vec<u8>> = s.split(pattern).map(|s| s.as_bytes().to_vec()).collect();
    println!("{:?}", new_vector);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=4acd355e66f63dad894713cc26b1566d)

Comment: I manipulate binaries (which can be not compatible utf8), so I prefer to find a pure vec solution.

Comment: Makes sense @soywod, I think in that case you can just create a function iterating over the elements. Should easily be done in `O(N)`.

Comment: The bstr crate provides string routines on byte slices, including split.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no `split` function in the std lib for byte slices (or anything else except strings really). You can however let the stdlib handle the looping for you using [`fold`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.fold):

```
let input = vec![
    1, 1, 1,
    98, 99,
    2, 2, 2, 2,
    98, 99,
    3, 3
];
let sep = vec![ 98, 99 ];
    
let acc = input.iter().fold (
    (vec![], vec![], 0),
    |(mut res, mut cur, count), &val| {
        if val == sep[count] {
            if count+1 == sep.len() {
                res.push (cur);
                (res, vec![], 0)
            } else {
                (res, cur, count+1)
            }
        } else if count != 0 {
            cur.extend_from_slice (&sep[..count]);
            (res, cur, 0)
        } else {
            cur.push (val);
            (res, cur, 0)
        }
    });
let mut output = acc.0;
if !acc.1.is_empty() { output.push (acc.1); }
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=release&edition=2018&gist=379601459da4d899c5b8dbf52fc4d3cd)

This can also be adapted to work with references, thus removing the need for the inputs to implement `Copy`:

```
let acc = input.iter().enumerate().fold (
    (vec![], 0, 0, 0),
    |(mut res, beg, end, count), (cur, val)| {
        if val == &sep[count] {
            if count+1 == sep.len() {
                res.push (&input[beg..end]);
                (res, cur+1, cur+1, 0)
            } else {
                (res, beg, end, count+1)
            }
        } else {
            (res, beg, cur+1, 0)
        }
    });
let mut output = acc.0;
if acc.1 < acc.2 { output.push (&input[acc.1 .. acc.2]); }
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=release&edition=2018&gist=291a1110172cc6313b6e10a3eecbd69b)

Note that the output of this second version is a vector of *slices* instead of a vector of vectors.